# Bash command substitution + parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, subshell

I'm confused how the quoting and parameter and glob expansion is supposed to work in a subshell. Does the quoting and expansions of the subshell command line always happen in the context of the subshell process? My test *seems* to confirm this.

```
Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ ls
a  b  c

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ echo "$(echo *)"
a b c
# The subshell expands the * glob

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ echo $(echo '*')
a b c
# The subshell outputs literal *, parent shell expands the * glob

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ echo $(echo "*")
a b c
# The subshell outputs literal *, parent shell expands the * glob

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ echo "$(echo '*')"
*
# The subshell outputs literal *, parent shell outputs literal *

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ foo=bar

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ echo "$(echo $foo)"
bar
# The subshell expands variable foo

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ echo $(echo '$foo')
$foo
# The subshell outputs literal $foo

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ echo $(echo "$foo")
bar
# The subshell expands variable foo

Tuomas@DESKTOP-LI5P50P MINGW64 ~/shell/test1/test
$ echo "$(echo '$foo')"
$foo
# The subshell outputs literal $foo
```

Am I correct? Is there any scenarios, where parents shell will somehow process or evaluate the subshell command line before forking?

Comment: You are correct. Parameter expansions in a subshell are run *in that subshell*. That said, it's not obvious to me what aspects of the truth/faultiness of that assertion most of your tests are intended to show.

Comment: A better way to test this would be to compare `echo "$BASHPID"` with `echo "$(echo "$BASHPID")"`

Comment: ...well, referring to the *quoting* is a different matter -- quoting is evaluated (on a character-by-character basis!) at parse time, whereas expansions happen at execution time. But the expansions always happen post-fork.

Comment: One thing that might help to ensure that an answer is useful and applicable: What's the real-world use case you're considering that hinges on the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsing -- thus, the determination of which content is quoted how -- happens *before* the fork. Because the forked-off copy of the shell has a copy-on-write instance of the memory of its parent process, it also has the parse tree, and inherits this information from its parent.

The parameter expansion (of `$foo` in your examples) happens *after* the fork. Similarly, the contents of `foo` are first string-split and glob-expanded to generate an argument list to pass to `echo` inside the subshell. Then that subshell runs `echo`, and the output written to stdout is read by the parent process (the original shell).

String-splitting and glob expansion of the command substitution's result (the content written by `echo`) happens back in the parent process, after it read the output of its child as a string.

Comment: So it's *never* possible for the bash to expand anything on the subshell command before the fork? For example, if I needed the value `$BASHPID` of the parent shell in the subshell command line, my only options is to assign it into a new variable, and let the subshell inherit and expand that variable? I mean to pass something about the parent, that is not known until the runtime.

Comment: Well, for `BASHPID` specifically there are other approaches (`$$` will be the parent shell's PID unless you're a subshell of a subshell, and you could pull the parent's process id out of procfs if targeting Linux), but in general, the statement above is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I meant in general. That clarified things

Comment: (that said, there aren't all that many aspects of a process that *aren't* copied on `fork()` and shared between parent and child, so if it isn't the PID you're trying to retrieve, I'm actually curious which non-shared/per-process data it is that's pertinent to your use case).

Comment: Just theoretical reflection to internalize the concepts :)

Comment: I thought the parent shell did the expansion of `$foo`.  Does shell parse what is enclosed inside `$( ... )` differently?

Comment: @codeforester, ...how would that work? If you ran, say, `echo "$(cd /; echo "$PWD")"`, the `PWD` *couldn't* be expanded until after the subshell has forked, tried to run the `cd`, and determined whether it succeeded.

Comment: That makes sense - `echo $PWD $(cd /some/other/dir; echo $PWD)` does show different values.  However, what explains `echo $$ $(echo $$)` echoing the same PID in both parent and the subshell?  Is `$$` a special case then?

Comment: @codeforester, that's because `$$` is *supposed to* return the PID of the primary instance of a shell -- by design and documentation -- even when run in a subshell. That's the whole reason `BASHPID` exists; there would be no need for it otherwise. (So `$$` is expanded by the child, but it uses a value initialized by the parent at invocation time).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @CharlesDuffy.  These primitives take a long time to sink in.   Found this related post in U&L stackoverflow: [Is a sub-shell the same thing as a child-shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261638/201820).